# How to use HasRecordID in JS Controller

Tags: lightning-events

I am trying to use the below function and I have implemented hasRecordId at the component level.

```
handleClick: function (component, event, helper) {
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": recordID // how can I use hasRecordId here?
        });
        navEvt.fire();
    }
```

Instead of mentioning the hard-coded value of ID here can someone please confirm how can I use the hasRecordID?

I have added this component in home page with lightning app builder.

Comment: Can you explain your use case?

Answer (score 1):

When you implement, [`hasRecordId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation) interface, Aura creates an Attribute in your component 'recordId' automatically. And as with any other attribute in lightning development, you would need to do the following to get it in JS controller:

`"recordId": component.get('v.recordId')`

From the documentation

> Add the `force:hasRecordId` interface to a Lightning component to enable
>   the component to be assigned the ID of the current record. The current
>   record ID is useful if the component is used on a **Lightning record
>   page**, as an object-specific custom action or action override in
>   Lightning Experience or the Salesforce app, and so on.

Comment: It is still not working :( getting an error "Invalid key RecordId"

Comment: It will work if your component is being used from with a Lightning record page, i.e. Account record page, where the account name is "Acme" and its Id will be in the "recordId" attribute.

Comment: I am using it from the lighting app builder

Comment: As I mentioned, it will work if are you using it in the lightning record page, as the platform picks the current record. In case of app builder, there is no current record.

Comment: Do we have any alternative to achieve the same from the home page?

Comment: You can have the record id in the url string as parameter or you can post another question, related to your use-case and we would be happy to help. current question doesn't cover that, I afraid.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for the same?

Comment: @gs650x please notice that javascxript is case sensitive, so you have to write `recordId` and not `RecordId` (so it looks from the error you wrote)

Comment: Yes Ltai, I am using recordId not RecordId

Comment: @gs650x you need to provide more details on your use-case. Either edit your question and enter the requirements so we could help you with alternate solutions, or as this question stands, accept most appropriate answer and open another question with requirements what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement the `force:hasRecordId` interface an attribute called `recordId` is included automatically in your lightning component.

This is the equivalent markup that is added in the background: `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>`

So in your javascript controller, you can reference this as usual:
`"recordId": component.get("v.recordId")`

Documentation is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation).

Comment: Hi Fred, Thank you for the response, I am using my component at home page and I have tried the above method already but still didn't get any luck, could you please suggest any other way?

Comment: Which record Id are you expecting?

Comment: I have a component which iterating the name of the Account on a page now I have added hyperlink to the name so that whenever we click on a name it will take us to the record page so I am expecting the record Id of the account name I am clicking on.